# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' despite dictionary being full

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis

I'm using Perspective API to get toxicity scores from Twitter data. However, I get this error even though my dictionary isn't empty `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`:

```
def getToxicityScores(sentence): 

analyze_request = {
    'comment': {
        'text': sentence },
    'requestedAttributes': {
        'TOXICITY': {}, 
        'INSULT': {}, 
        'IDENTITY_ATTACK': {}, 
        'THREAT': {}
    }
}

response = client.comments().analyze(body=analyze_request).execute()
#print(response.get('attributeScores', {}))
print(response.keys())

perspect_dict = {
    'Profanity': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('PROFANITY').get('spanScores')[0].get('score').get('value'), 
    'Toxicity': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('TOXICITY').get('spanScores')[0].get('score').get('value'), 
    'Threat': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('THREAT').get('spanScores')[0].get('score').get('value'), 
    'IdentityAttack': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('IDENTITY_ATTACK').get('spanScores')[0].get('score').get('value'), 
    'Insult': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('INSULT').get('spanScores')[0].get('score').get('value')
}

time.sleep(40)

return perspect_dict
```

My call: `getToxicityScores('shut up')`**strong text**

Comment: Just a guess: You are missing `PROFANITY` in your `analyze_request`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add appropriate default values to all the `.get()` calls. If there's no `attributeScores` key in the `response` dictionary, you return an empty dictionary from the first `.get()`, and then all the following `.get()` calls will return `None` by default. This will then get an error when you try to call `.get('spanScores')`.

And you need to give `.get('spanScores')` a default that allows `[0].get('score')` to work. And so on.

```
perspect_dict = {
    'Profanity': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('PROFANITY', {}).get('spanScores', [{}])[0].get('score', {}).get('value', 0), 
    'Toxicity': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('TOXICITY', {}).get('spanScores', [{}])[0].get('score', {}).get('value', 0), 
    'Threat': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('THREAT, {}').get('spanScores', [{}])[0].get('score', {}).get('value', 0), 
    'IdentityAttack': response.get('attributeScores', {}).get('IDENTITY_ATTACK', {}).get('spanScores', [{}])[0].get('score', {}).get('value', 0), 
    'Insult': response.get('attributeScores', {}, [{}]).get('INSULT', {}).get('spanScores')[0].get('score', {}).get('value', 0)
}
```

This would be easier if you put that chain of `.get` calls into a function, so you could just call it repeatedly instead of repeating all this code.